# Semi-solid colored box around lists

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\tikzset{
mymat/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    text height=2.5ex,
    text depth=0.75ex,
    text width=3.25ex,
    align=center,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth
},
mymats/.style={
    mymat,
    nodes={draw,fill=#1}
}  
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,0) 
(mat1)
{   
     & \\
     N1 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat1,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat2)
{
 & \\
    t_2 & t_4 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-1) 
(mat3)
{   
    & \\
    N2 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat3,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat4)
{
    &  &  \\
    t_1 & t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-2) 
(mat5)
{   
    & \\
    N3 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat5,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat6)
{
    & &\\
    t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-3) 
(mat7)
{   
    & \\
    N4 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat7,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat8)
{
    & \\
    t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-4) 
(mat9)
{   
    & \\
    N5 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat9,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat10)
{
    & \\
    t_1 & t_3  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (2,-5) 
(mat11)
{   
    & & & &\\
    t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5\\
};

\begin{scope}[shorten <= -2pt]
\draw[*->]
(mat1-2-1.east) -- (mat2-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat3-2-1.east) -- (mat4-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat5-2-1.east) -- (mat6-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat7-2-1.east) -- (mat8-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat9-2-1.east) -- (mat10-2-1.west);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Wants to draw the red part of the image. See attachment. 
[image]

Part of the code is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228849/122134)

Comment: Your code do not compile (missing `mymat` style). And when compiled do not correspond to your drawing. For the solution you can try `\draw[red, dashed] (mat2.north west) rectangle (mat10.south -| mat4.east);` or use `fit` library with `\node[draw,red, dashed,fit=(mat2)(mat4)(mat6)(mat8)(mat10)]{};`

Comment: When you copy a code (in your case [from here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228849)) it is a good practice to credit the used answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning,arrows.meta,arrows}
\begin{document}
\tikzset{
mymat/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    text height=2.5ex,
    text depth=0.75ex,
    text width=3.25ex,
    align=center,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth
},
mymats/.style={
    mymat,
    nodes={draw,fill=#1}
}  
}


\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,0) 
(mat1)
{   
     & \\
     N1 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat1,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat2)
{
 & \\
    t_2 & t_4 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-1) 
(mat3)
{   
    & \\
    N2 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat3,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat4)
{
    &  &  \\
    t_1 & t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-2) 
(mat5)
{   
    & \\
    N3 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat5,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat6)
{
    & &\\
    t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-3) 
(mat7)
{   
    & \\
    N4 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat7,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat8)
{
    & \\
    t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-4) 
(mat9)
{   
    & \\
    N5 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat9,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat10)
{
    & \\
    t_1 & t_3  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (2,-5.5) 
(mat11)
{   
    & & & &\\
    t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 & t_5\\
};

\node[draw,dashed,red,fit=(mat10-2-1) (mat2-2-1) (mat4-2-3),inner sep=2mm] (f1){};
\draw[red,->] (f1) to[out=-90,in=90] (mat11-2-3.north);
\begin{scope}[shorten <= -2pt]
\draw[*->]
(mat1-2-1.east) -- (mat2-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat3-2-1.east) -- (mat4-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat5-2-1.east) -- (mat6-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat7-2-1.east) -- (mat8-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat9-2-1.east) -- (mat10-2-1.west);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{document}
```

[image]