# Joining corners of a node and matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

```
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,shapes,arrows,shadows,patterns}
\tikzset{
 mymat/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    text height=2.5ex,
    text depth=0.75ex,
    text width=3.25ex,
    align=center,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth
},
mymats/.style={
    mymat,
    nodes={draw,fill=#1}
}  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,0) 
(mat1)
{   
     & \\
     N1 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat1,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat2)
{
     & \\
    t_2 & t_4 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-1) 
(mat3)
{   
& \\
N2 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat3,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat4)
{
&  &  \\
t_1 & t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-2) 
(mat5)
{   
& \\
N3 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat5,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat6)
{
& &\\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-3) 
(mat7)
{   
    & \\
    N4 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat7,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat8)
{
& \\
t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-4) 
(mat9)
{   
& \\
N5 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat9,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat10)
{
& \\
t_1 & t_3  \\
};

\matrix[mymat, anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
at (1.65,-5.5) 
(mat11)
{   
& & & \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4\\
};
\node[ draw, red, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(mat2)(mat4)(mat6)(mat8) 
(mat10)](node1){};
\begin{scope}[shorten <= -2pt]
\draw[*->]
(mat1-2-1.east) -- (mat2-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat3-2-1.east) -- (mat4-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat5-2-1.east) -- (mat6-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat7-2-1.east) -- (mat8-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat9-2-1.east) -- (mat10-2-1.west);

\end{scope}
\draw[green, dashed](node1.south west) -- (mat11.north west);
\draw[green, dashed](node1.south east) -- (mat11.north east);

\end{tikzpicture} 
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Unable to join the corners of node1 and mat11 with green dashed lines.

Part of the code is taken from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228835/how-to-draw-adjacency-array-with-tikz/228849#228849)

Solution provided [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29874/properly-aligning-drawn-lines-between-the-corners-of-2-rectangular-nodes-in-tikz) is elegant though, didn't work for this figure.

Comment: Your example code is missing two libraries by the way, `fit` and `matrix`, as well as a `\documentclass`. And of course, it's not necessary to load `tikz` twice. You're actually loading it three times, as `pgfplots` loads `tikz` as well.

Comment: See updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, I think your problem comes from the fact that a `\matrix` is just a special type of `\node`, and like all nodes it has a (by default non-zero) `inner sep`. You can see that if you add `draw` to the options of `mat11`, so that you have

```
\matrix[mymat, draw, anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
at (1.65,-5.5) 
(mat11)
{   
& & & \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4\\
};
```

which gives this:

[image]

So the lines you've drawn goes to the corners of the outer border, not the corners of the nodes.

I can think of two ways around this:

1. Draw the lines to `mat11-2-1.north west` and `mat11-2-4.north east` instead of `mat11.north west`/`mat11.north east`. This way the lines point to the nodes inside the matrix, instead of the matrix itself.

   ```
   \draw[green, dashed](node1.south west) -- (mat11-2-1.north west);
   \draw[green, dashed](node1.south east) -- (mat11-2-4.north east);
   ```

   [image]
2. Set the `inner sep` of `mat11` to 0, but then you have to set the `inner sep` of the `nodes` back to `0.333em`, which is the default value:

   ```
   \matrix[mymat, inner sep=0, anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30,inner sep=0.333em}}]
   at (1.65,-5.5) 
   (mat11)
   {   
   & & & \\
   t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4\\
   };
   ```

   [image]

Complete code with both methods:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning,arrows}
\tikzset{
 mymat/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    text height=2.5ex,
    text depth=0.75ex,
    text width=3.25ex,
    align=center,
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
},
mymats/.style={
    mymat,
    nodes={draw,fill=#1}
}  
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,0) 
(mat1)
{   
     & \\
     N1 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat1,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat2)
{
     & \\
    t_2 & t_4 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-1) 
(mat3)
{   
& \\
N2 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat3,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat4)
{
&  &  \\
t_1 & t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-2) 
(mat5)
{   
& \\
N3 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat5,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat6)
{
& &\\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-3) 
(mat7)
{   
    & \\
    N4 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat7,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat8)
{
& \\
t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-4) 
(mat9)
{   
& \\
N5 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat9,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat10)
{
& \\
t_1 & t_3  \\
};

\matrix[mymat, inner sep=0, anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30,inner sep=0.333em}}]
at (1.65,-5.5) 
(mat11)
{   
& & & \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4\\
};


\node[ draw, red, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(mat2)(mat4)(mat6)(mat8) 
(mat10)](node1){};
\begin{scope}[shorten <= -2pt]
\draw[*->]
(mat1-2-1.east) -- (mat2-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat3-2-1.east) -- (mat4-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat5-2-1.east) -- (mat6-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat7-2-1.east) -- (mat8-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat9-2-1.east) -- (mat10-2-1.west);

\end{scope}
\draw[green, dashed](node1.south west) -- (mat11.north west);
\draw[green, dashed](node1.south east) -- (mat11.north east);

\end{tikzpicture} 

\bigskip

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,0) 
(mat1)
{   
     & \\
     N1 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat1,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat2)
{
     & \\
    t_2 & t_4 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-1) 
(mat3)
{   
& \\
N2 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat3,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat4)
{
&  &  \\
t_1 & t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-2) 
(mat5)
{   
& \\
N3 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat5,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat6)
{
& &\\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-3) 
(mat7)
{   
    & \\
    N4 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat7,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat8)
{
& \\
t_3 & t_4  \\
};
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,-4) 
(mat9)
{   
& \\
N5 \\
};

\matrix[mymat,right=of mat9,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
(mat10)
{
& \\
t_1 & t_3  \\
};


\matrix[mymat, anchor=west,row 2/.style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
at (1.65,-5.5) 
(mat11)
{   
& & & \\
t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4\\
};

\node[ draw, red, dashed, line width=0.7pt, fit=(mat2)(mat4)(mat6)(mat8) 
(mat10)](node1){};
\begin{scope}[shorten <= -2pt]
\draw[*->]
(mat1-2-1.east) -- (mat2-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat3-2-1.east) -- (mat4-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat5-2-1.east) -- (mat6-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat7-2-1.east) -- (mat8-2-1.west);
\draw[*->]
(mat9-2-1.east) -- (mat10-2-1.west);

\end{scope}
\draw[green, dashed](node1.south west) -- (mat11-2-1.north west);
\draw[green, dashed](node1.south east) -- (mat11-2-4.north east);

\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

## Addendum

As mentioned in a comment, I don't think it's necessary to use a `\matrix` for the `N` nodes on the left. I don't understand the purpose of the empty first row in your matrices either, seems you're adding a lot of unnecessary code. Here is one alternative method for making your diagram. I make use of the `chains` library to create the `N` nodes on the left (could also have used a `\matrix`, actually). Everything is placed relative to other stuff, so no explicit coordinates are used. To draw the arrows, I used a loop.

I used the `arrows.meta` library instead of `arrows`, as TikZ considers the latter to be deprecated in favor of the former (see the manual for version 3.0.1a  page 512).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,fit,positioning,chains,arrows.meta}
\tikzset{
 nodestyle/.style={ 
    text height=2.5ex,
    text depth=0.75ex,
    text width=3.25ex,
    align=center,
    draw
},
 mymat/.style={
    matrix of math nodes,
    nodes={
      nodestyle,
      fill=gray!30,
    },
    column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
}  
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1.2cm]
\begin{scope}[
  start chain=N going below,
  every node/.style={
     nodestyle,
     on chain
  },
  node distance=2mm
]    
  \node {$N1$};
  \node {$N2$};
  \node {$N3$};
  \node {$N4$};
  \node {$N5$};
\end{scope}

\matrix [mymat,right=of N-1, name=m1] {t_2 & t_4 \\ };
\matrix [mymat,right=of N-2, name=m2] {t_1 & t_3 & t_4 \\ };
\matrix [mymat,right=of N-3, name=m3] {t_1 & t_2 & t_3 \\ };
\matrix [mymat,right=of N-4, name=m4] {t_3 & t_4 \\ };
\matrix [mymat,right=of N-5, name=m5] {t_1 & t_3 \\ };


\node [draw, red, dashed, fit=(m1)(m2)(m3)(m4)(m5), name=M] {};

\foreach \i in {1,...,5}
   \draw [Circle-Latex,shorten <=-2pt] (N-\i) -- (m\i-1-1);


\matrix [mymat,below=5mm of M, name=m11] {t_1 & t_2 & t_3 & t_4 \\ };

\draw[green, dashed](M.south west) -- (m11-1-1.north west);
\draw[green, dashed](M.south east) -- (m11-1-4.north east);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I don't understand why you're using `\matrix` for all the `Nn` nodes though, seems unnecessary. I'll edit in a bit, showing one possible other method for making this diagram.