# How to draw the image full of arrays

Tags: tikz-pgf, diagrams

I don't know how to make the image given below.

[image]

see my code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (s) at (0,0);
    \foreach \num in {5,2,7,-5,16,12}{
      \node[minimum size=6mm, draw, rectangle] at (s) {\num};
      \coordinate (s) at ($(s) + (1,0)$);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Question : How to draw the image given in the diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code (that is heavily inspired by [Gonzalo Medina's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/228849/134144)) might serve as a starting point:

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,positioning,arrows.meta,arrows}

\tikzset{
mymat/.style={
  matrix of math nodes,
  text height=2.5ex,
  text depth=0.75ex,
  text width=3.25ex,
  align=center,
  row sep=-\pgflinewidth
  },
}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=latex]
\matrix[mymat,anchor=west,style={nodes=draw}]
at (0,0) 
(mat1)
{
1\\
2\\
3\\
4\\
5\\
6\\
7\\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat1,anchor=south,style={nodes={draw}},yshift=1.5cm]
(mat2)
{
1\\
2\\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat2,anchor=center,style={nodes={draw}}]
(mat3)
{
1\\
2\\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat3,anchor=center,style={nodes={draw}}]
(mat4)
{
1\\
2\\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat1,anchor=north,style={nodes={draw}},yshift=-1.5cm]
(mat5)
{
1\\
2\\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat5,anchor=center,style={nodes={draw}}]
(mat6)
{
1\\
2\\
};
\matrix[mymat,right=of mat6,anchor=center,style={nodes={draw}}]
(mat7)
{
1\\
2\\
};
\path[->]
  (mat1-1-1.center) edge[bend left=50] node [left] {} (mat2-1-1.north west);
\path[->]
  (mat1-1-1.center) edge[bend left=60] node [left] {} (mat3-1-1.north west);
\path[->]
  (mat1-1-1.center) edge[bend left=70] node [left] {} (mat4-1-1.north west);
\path[->]
  (mat1-7-1.center) edge[bend left=50] node [left] {} (mat5-1-1.north west);
\path[->]
  (mat1-7-1.center) edge[bend left=60] node [left] {} (mat6-1-1.north west);
\path[->]
  (mat1-7-1.center) edge[bend left=70] node [left] {} (mat7-1-1.north west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Instead of `column sep=-\pgflinewidth` I would use `row sep=-\pgflinewidth`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but there are few problems with the answer. 1) pointing arrays are small 2) big arrays are is not numbered as required.

Comment: @CarLaTeX: Thank you for your comment. Indeed using row sep for a vertical array makes much more sense than using column sep.

Comment: @I_wil_break_wall: My answer was not intended to be a complete code that exactly replicates the sketch in your image. Instead some more finetunig is needed. Regarding the size of the arrays, you can easily add more rows following the same pattern. Adjustments regarding the alignment can be done using for example the `anchor` option. Regarding the numbers left of the arrays, you might want to have a closer look at the answer that I liked in my answer. This numbering scheme of a horizontal array should be easily applicable to a vertical array as well.

Comment: @leandriis +1 for [the comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/476471/how-to-draw-the-image-full-of-arrays#comment1204367_476490)!