# How to draw a merge sort algorithm figure?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I am trying to draw following [merge sort algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_algorithm#/media/File:Merge_sort_algorithm_diagram.svg) picture. Please note that answer for [How to draw a list that its items point to a structure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591759/127048) helpful for a starting point.

[image]

---

Following section is related to main question where how can I put a caption on top of each array node, simple example on the main part of the question would be helpful:

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here the `tree` option is useful. In order to have everything well aligned, you need to draw two trees, one growing down and one growing up. I used `rectangle split` option from `shapes.multipart` library but you can also do it with matrices of nodes.

[image: Merge sort alg]

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.multipart}

\tikzset{block/.style={
        font=\sffamily,
        draw=black,
        thin,
        fill=pink!50,
        rectangle split,
        rectangle split horizontal,
        rectangle split parts=#1,
        outer sep=0pt},
        %
        gblock/.style={
            block,
            rectangle split parts=#1,
            fill=green!30}
        }

\begin{document}
    
    \def\lvld{1.2}                  % Choose level distance
    \pgfmathsetmacro\shft{-6*\lvld} % Calculate the yshift for the green tree
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[level distance=\lvld cm,
                        level 1/.style={sibling distance=4cm},
                        level 2/.style={sibling distance=2cm},
                        level 3/.style={sibling distance=1cm},
                        edgedown/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=red,thick,-latex}},
                        edgeup/.style={edge from parent/.style={draw=green!50!black,thick,latex-}}
                        ]
  
        % GREEN TREE (drawn first to let the middle line filled in pink)

        \node[gblock=7,yshift=\shft cm] (A') {3 \nodepart{two} 9 \nodepart{three} 10 \nodepart{four} 27 \nodepart{five} 39 \nodepart{six}43 \nodepart{seven}82}
            [grow=up,edgeup]
            child {node[gblock=3] (B2') {9 \nodepart{two} 10 \nodepart{three} 82}
                child {node[gblock=1] (C4') {10}
                    child {node[gblock=1] (D7') {10}}
                }
                child {node[gblock=2] (C2') {9 \nodepart{two} 82}
                    child {node[gblock=1] (D3') {82}}
                    child {node[gblock=1] (D4') {9}}
                    }
                }
            child {node[gblock=4] (B1') {3 \nodepart{two} 27 \nodepart{three} 39 \nodepart{four} 43}
                child {node[gblock=2] (C3') {3 \nodepart{two} 43}
                    child {node[gblock=1] (D5') {3}}
                    child {node[gblock=1] (D6') {43}}
                }
                child {node[gblock=2] (C1') {27 \nodepart{two} 39}
                    child {node[gblock=1] (D1') {27}}
                    child {node[gblock=1] (D2') {39}}
                    }
            };
            
            
        % PINK TREE
        
        \node[block=7] (A) {39 \nodepart{two} 27 \nodepart{three} 43 \nodepart{four} 3 \nodepart{five} 9 \nodepart{six}82 \nodepart{seven}10}
            [grow=down,edgedown]
            child {node[block=4] (B1) {39 \nodepart{two} 27 \nodepart{three} 43 \nodepart{four} 3}
                child {node[block=2] (C1) {39 \nodepart{two} 27}
                    child {node[block=1] (D1) {39}}
                    child {node[block=1] (D2) {27}}
                    }
                child {node[block=2] (C2) {43 \nodepart{two} 3}
                    child {node[block=1] (D3) {43}}
                    child {node[block=1] (D4) {3}}
                    }
                }
            child {node[block=3] (B2) {9 \nodepart{two} 82 \nodepart{three} 10}
                child {node[block=2] (C3) {9 \nodepart{two} 82}
                    child {node[block=1] (D5) {9}}
                    child {node[block=1] (D6) {82}}
                }
                child {node[block=1] (C4) {10}
                    child {node[block=1] (D7) {10}}
                }
            };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

You can also see that every array is a specific node and so has its own name. You can now do about everything you want in Ti*k*Z around those nodes, by pointing to or from them.

Comment: Is it possible to label array linked by a line like on bottom picture on my question?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I said in the bottom of the post, one may add anything using the nodes names. Say, you want to label the bottom array (named `(A')`), you can by typing something like `\draw (A') --++ (1,-1) node {foo};`. Just give it a try.

Comment: I did but when I put a new line after foo ex `\draw (mat2-1-1.north) --++ (0,0.5) node[align=center] {\tiny foo\\\tiny doo};` the new line distance is pretty long , is it possible to make ti shorter ?/

Comment: Since what you write above is not in any relation with my answer (I did not use matrices), I suggest that you ask another question regarding your new issue.

Comment: @SebGlab Please see: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/592325/how-to-draw-multiple-line-caption-linked-by-a-line : you can also observe that middle lines in between the boxes are double bolded which I couldn't fix