# How to draw multiple line caption linked by a line?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to draw multiple lines caption that is connected to a line. I observe that line may overwrite to second line.

Base figure example would be right hand side of the following figure (taken from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms second edition, page 223):

[image]

---

my code: (it generates an error but able to compile)

```
\documentclass[tikz, margin=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta,arrows,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    mymat/.style={
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum width=1cm,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      text height=2.5ex,
      text depth=0.75ex,
      text width=3.25ex,
      align=center,
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      outer sep=0pt,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    mymat3/.style={
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum width=0.5cm,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      text height=2.5ex,
      text depth=0.75ex,
      text width=3.25ex,
      align=center,
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      outer sep=0pt,
      inner sep=0pt
      }
    }
\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix[mymat,anchor=south west,style={nodes=draw}]
      at (5*\x+0.3,-3.6)
      (mat1)
      {
        400\\
        100\\
      };

      \draw (mat1-1-1.north west) --++ (0,0.8);
      \draw (mat1-1-1.north east) --++ (0,0.8);

      \matrix[mymat3,right=25mm of mat1-1-1.east,anchor=east,style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
      (mat2)
      {
        1 & 2 & \dots\\
      };

      \matrix[mymat3,below=0.5 mm of mat2,style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
      (mat5)
      {
        1 & 2 & \dots\\
      };

      \path[->, -Latex]
      (mat1-2-1.east) edge[] node [left] {} (mat5-1-1.west);
      \path[->, -Latex]
      (mat1-1-1.east) edge[] node [left] {} (mat2-1-1.west);

      \foreach \i [count=\l from 0] in {2,...,1} \node[left= 0.1mm of mat1-\i-1] {\l};
      \draw (mat2-1-1.north) --++ (0,0.5) node[align=center] {\tiny available\\\tiny life};
      \draw (mat2-1-2.north) --++ (0,0.5) node[align=center] {\tiny core\\\tiny number};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{M1}\label{fig:M1}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Here, I have done `draw (mat2-1-1.north) --++ (0,0.5) node[align=center] {\tiny available\\\tiny life};` to link caption along with a line but the line is linked to the first sentences where it overwrites to text after the new line (`life` and `number` strings in the example). And also there is a gap in between the lines that I couldn't remove.

Desired picuture could be, or any variaty that captions won't collide :

[image]

Related answers:

- [How to draw a merge sort algorithm figure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/592169/127048)
- [How to draw a list that its items point to a structure?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/591759/127048)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Improvements had to be made here and there. You still need to learn some Ti*k*Z basics to produce a straight code. You're on the good way ;) Hope that helps.

[image: matrices of nodes with captions]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{tikzpeople}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,calc,arrows.meta,arrows,matrix}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathreplacing}

\tikzset{
    mymat/.style={
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum width=1cm,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      text height=2.5ex,
      text depth=0.75ex,
      text width=3.25ex,
      align=center,
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      outer sep=0pt,
      inner sep=0pt
    },
    mymat3/.style={
      matrix of math nodes,
      minimum width=0.5cm,
      minimum height=0.5cm,
      text height=2.5ex,
      text depth=0.75ex,
      text width=3.25ex,
      align=center,
      row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
      outer sep=0pt,
      inner sep=0pt
      }
    }
\begin{document}

  \begin{figure}
    \centering

    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \matrix[mymat,anchor=south west,style={nodes=draw}]
      (mat1) at (0.3,-3.6)
        {
        400\\
        100\\
      };

      \draw (mat1-1-1.north west) --++ (0,0.8);
      \draw (mat1-1-1.north east) --++ (0,0.8);

      \matrix[mymat3,right=8mm of mat1-2-1.south east,anchor=south west,style={nodes={draw,fill=gray!30}}]
      (mat2)
      {
        1 & 2 & \dots\\
        1 & 2 & \dots\\
      };


      \draw[-Latex]
      (mat1-1-1.east) -- (mat2-1-1.west);
      \draw[-Latex]
      (mat1-2-1.east) -- (mat2-2-1.west);

      \foreach \i [count=\l from 0] in {2,...,1} \node[left= 0.1mm of mat1-\i-1] {\l};
      
      \tikzset{
              lblnode/.style={
                text width=1cm,
                align=center,
                anchor=south,
                inner sep=1pt,
                execute at begin node=\setlength{\baselineskip}{3pt}
                }
               }
      \draw (mat2-1-1.north) --++ (-0.25,0.5) node[lblnode] {\tiny available life};
      \draw (mat2-1-2.north) --++ (0.25,0.5) node[lblnode] {\tiny core number};
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{M1}\label{fig:M1}
  \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

### EDIT

Following OP's question about row and column sep, here are some examples of how to modify them.

#### 1. No gap, no *bold* line

```
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
```

[image: no gap, no bold lines]

#### 2. Separated rows

```
row sep=2pt,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
```

[image: separated rows]

#### 3. Separated columns

```
row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=2pt,
```

[image: separated columns]

Comment: Sorry for asking too many questions, and appreciated your help :) // Is it normal that middle line in between the boxes is double bolded (ex: line in between 1 and 2)? is it possible to make the line normal bold line ?

Comment: Could there be a small space in between the vertical gray arrays? I have modified `minimum height` but it didn't have any affect

Comment: Just add `column sep=-\pgflinewidth,` to your matrix declaration, like you did for the rows, and change `row sep` to something positive. I'll edit my post to let you choose.

Comment: Thanks, I was also able to fix it via changing heighs for `mat3`: `minimum height=0.3cm,` and `text height=2.1ex,` but not sure would it be a proper solution

Comment: Where should I add `row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
column sep=-\pgflinewidth,` at which line in your original answer code? that would be helpful

Comment: You should do that in your declaration of `mymat3/.style`. Here, you only have `row sep=-\pgflinewidth`. Play here with those settings.